# Context of required files within a single Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, game-engine

So this is probably really simple but I can't find the right words to Google this myself. I just started studying Ruby on SoloLearn and one of their examples was a very simple RPG game (really just a single fight) and it seemed like the perfect practice project. I have a gem structured like this:

```
Game/
     game.gemspec
     lib/
         game.rb
         chars.rb
```

`game.rb` has the class `Player` which should be a superclass of each character  class (char types for ambiguity) in `chars.rb`. Can classes in `chars.rb` inherit from classes in `game.rb`?

Comment: Please consider reformatting your question by using [this style guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Yes, they can inherit, all the files in `lib` will be accessible either thru autoloading, or using `require`, or `require_relative`. You can also add your player into it's own `lib/player.rb` file, which is generally how you'll see it done. If you had a sublcass of type "Rogue", you might even consider putting that in `lib/player/rogue.rb` if you want to keep your code separated.

Comment: @anothermh sorry the most markdown i know is br and headers so ill have to check that out!  .@. Jay thanks... could you expand on that a little and post it as an answer plz

Comment: @Myersj281 sure thing. Let me put a sample together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `require` and `require_relative` to import code from other files in your codebase, or other libraries you've installed. You can use these methods along with using folders to organize your code to keep things neat.

I uploaded a very, very basic sample so you can see how some of the imports work:

https://github.com/jaydorsey/game

I tried to illustrate how you can use folders and `require_relative` to try and organize your code.

The ruby docs have more detail on both methods:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require

Answer (score 1):

Ruby uses `require` to import other files.

Some concepts to understand this better,

- `require` imports another Ruby file.
- When Ruby imports a file the code in, that file is executed line by line.
- When a class definition is executed, the class added to the global namespace.
- Thus, after importing the file that defines your class any file can access your class even if it does not import that file directly. To avoid nasty surprises though it is best to either repeat the require statements whenever you use a class or to rely on autoloading, as for example Rails does. Ruby keeps track of all imported files, so even if you import them more than once it will not execute them more than once.

Fun fact, you can print the name of all imported files using

```
puts $"
```